# Group integer values in a 2D Java Array and sum related values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, integer

I have created a 2D integer array in java which prints the below

```
1122, 10, 20

3344, 20, 30

1122, 20, 20

1122, 10, 10

3344, 10, 40
```

I am trying to now iterate over the above and create a new 2D array. I want to group by the first column and sum the other integer values associated with the number in first column, to end up with a resultant array like this:

```
1122, 40, 50

3344, 30, 70
```

What would be the best method in achieving this?

------ **EDIT** ------

Using the second answer below I have been able to generate a nested list, like the below:

```
[1122, 40, 50]

[3344, 30, 70]
```

Is it possible to get the result directly as a 2D integer array that I can work with and manipulate instead of a nested list?

I have tried to convert the nested list with the code below but cannot get this to compile successfully.

```
int[][] collectarray = new int[collect.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < collectarray.length; i++) {

 collectarray[i] = new int[collect.get(i).size()];

}

for (int i = 0; i < collect.size(); i++) {

 for (int j = 0; j < collect.get(i).size(); j++) {

  collectarray[i][j] = collect.get(i).get(j);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution with stream api:

```
List<int[]> collect = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ints -> ints[0]))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new int[]{
        entry.getKey(),   // [0]
        entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(value -> value[1]).sum(), // [1]
        entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(value -> value[2]).sum()  // [2]
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And print the result

```
collect.forEach(ints -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints)));
```

**Update**

If you want to get the result in 2D array directly you can use `toArray()` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList());`

```
int[][] collect = Arrays.stream(arr)
    ...
    ...
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to create a nested list successfully using this approach. Is it possible to get the result directly as a 2D integer array that I can work with and manipulate instead of a nested list?

I have tried to convert the nested list with the code in my edit above but cannot get this to compile successfully.

Comment: @engage_roll you can get 2d array directly, see updated answer. Glad to help!

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, works great. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Map to hold the items in the first column. Search on that and if it exists add the values you want to add If it does not then add the new value. Once you have iterated through your Array then Iterate through the map.